# Iterate over a fixed array

Tags: ruby, arrays, loops, bit

I have an array (`array1`) that is 19 bits long initialized to `0` and another array (`clave`) that is 64 bits long. I want to iterate over `array1` 64 times while `clave` is also been checked. I did this:

```
def fase2
    j=0
    for i in 0..63
        @array1[j]=@array1[18].to_i^@array1[17].to_i^@array1[16].to_i^@array1[13].to_i^@clave[i].to_i
    j=j+1
    if j>19  
        j=0  
    end  
    end
    print @array1
    gets
end
```

is there a cleaner way to do this...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a few improvements.

1. Call all of your variable names something more meaningful. What is in `@array1`? Integers? consider calling it `@ints`. Its good to call arrays a plural name. Same goes for `j` and `i` if possible.
2. Use `(0..63).each do |i|` instead of `for i in 0..63`. More ruby-like
3. Use spacing between operators, especially equals. `j = 0` not `j=0`
4. Small conditionals can go on one line: `j = 0 if j > 19`
5. Why the magic numbers? Why are 18, 17, 16, and 13 special? Put them in an appropriately named array to start, and then use Array#reduce like so

   ```
   special_indeces = [18, 17, 16, 13]

   ... and then in loop ...

   xor = special_indeces.reduce do |val, index|
     val ^ @array1[index].to_i
   end
   ```
6. What is with `gets` at the end? What is the point of that?

Good luck, that code needs *serious* work.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but it's more how I'd write the inner loops:

```
def fase2
  @clave.each do |clave|
    (0..19).each do |j|
      @array1[j] = @array1[18].to_i ^ @array1[17].to_i ^ @array1[16].to_i ^ @array1[13].to_i ^ clave.to_i
    end
  end
  print @array1
  gets
end
```